# SVG transparency not preserved on iOS (iPad/iPhone)

Tags: ios, css, iphone, svg

I have an SVG that doesn't seem to work with iOS devices.

I've tried in both chrome and safari only the SVG appears as a solid blue block colour and doesn't preserve the different layers and their opacity levels...

https://jsfiddle.net/2fLuspdm/

```
<svg version="1.0" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 1920 3840" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 3840;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">    
        .st0{opacity:6.000000e-02;fill:#609FD0;enable-background:new    ;}
    </style>
    <polygon class="st0" points="1920,2614 1920,3641 1470,3005.1 "/>
    <polygon class="st0" points="1920,1612.4 1210,780 1920,0.4 "/>
    <polyline class="st0" points="0,0 650,0 0,1184.3 1,0 "/>
    <polygon class="st0" points="0,898.4 960,1457 0,2778.4 "/>
    <polygon class="st0" points="0,3837.4 0,2654 1040,3840 "/>
    <polygon class="st0" points="1920,2926 1424,2239 1920,1046 "/>
    <polygon class="st0" points="829,3840 1920,2926 1936,3840 "/>
    <polygon class="st0" points="0,2530 0,1760 960,2909 "/>
    <polygon class="st0" points="1920,0.4 1920,622 40,0.4 "/>
    <polygon class="st0" points="1920,1634.5 1920,2404.5 1150,1435.5 "/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply compute the exponential (not sure if it's valid SVG syntax, but Safari doesn't like it).

```
<style type="text/css">    
    .st0{opacity:.06; fill:#609FD0; enable-background:new ;}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks @duopixel, that worked a charm! If I use it as an image however it still renders in incorreclty, just a blue mask really ...

https://jsfiddle.net/2fLuspdm/5/

any ideas?

Comment: Your source image still contains the exponential http://liamg.co.uk/bt.svg (view source) and it would be worth cleaning up the mess left by Illustrator.